# Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am attempting to run the following code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.89, openai_api_key="apikey")
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")

    zapier = ZapierNLAWrapper(zapier_nla_api_key="nlakey")
    toolkit = ZapierToolkit.from_zapier_nla_wrapper(zapier)

    # tools = [TweeterPostTool()] + toolkit.get_tools() + load_tools(["human"])

    tools = toolkit.get_tools() + load_tools(["human"])
```

However when i attempt to run it i got the following error
:NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases.

I have tried to install the langchain-0.0.350 version as was recommended in a  previous post regarding this issue however i have had no luck. et me know if you need any more details regarding the code. thank you for your time